# installing android sdk 23

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am updating android sdk 23 and i'm getting this error. I am using windows xp.

Error:
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

```
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.0.1245622 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.0.1245622)
  Software currently installed: Android Developer Tools 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    ADT Package 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
    ADT Package 23.0.0.1245622 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package 23.0.0.1245622)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 23.0.0.1245622 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.0.1245622)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package [23.0.0.1245622]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package [22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: ADT Package 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.2.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Developer Tools 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group [22.3.0.v201310242005-887826]
```

Comment: Installed eclipse from eclipse.org and installed adt it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, and was thinking of downloading a clean copy of Eclipse and then going through the installation of all the plug-in, but the sheer amount of hard work defeated my resolve.

I found another way out to update ADT 23 without any hassles on the current instance of Eclipse. :)

I was not sure if the approach will work or not, hence I did not capture the process, Please bear with me. In any case I can't post images I do not have reputation :P

Here's what I did:

1. Go to the Install new Software option from Help.
2. Open the available software sites.
3. Select Your Android site and remove it. Before removing copy the Location, we are going to use the same URL again.
4. Click OK (this will take you back to the previous screen).
5. paste the copied URL back into the "Work With" combo on the screen. Click Add.
6. It will flash a message saying it already has the options available.
7. Choose to uninstall the previous version and install new.

Voila, it installs ADT 23.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes. as I am writing this, my code is compiling in the background.

Comment: Good. Congratulations this bug eaten lots of time across countries hope Google won't repeat this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem in the SDK tools rev. 23 update of Google. A lot of people have problems with this upgrade, see:

- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72584
- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419

The only solution so far is to download a clean version of Eclipse.

I don't like to start with a clean copy and install all the other plugins, so I'll try to copy the SDK folders from this Clean Eclipse instance to your current one.

Edit:

I ended up with setting up a clean copy because I did not want to start more problems. I did the following:

- download the Eclipse (luna) bundle you like to use: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
- install Android SDK

I could not update the SDK itself to version 23 so I had to do the following

- download the Eclipse Android bundle
- make a backup your current android-sdk folder
- unzip and copy the sdk folder and copy it over the old android-sdk folder
  (The new SDK folder only contains 4.4)

Now you should have a working eclipse and you can start installing all the other plugins you like to use again.